# Fermat's principle: when does light actually travel along the local maximum of accumulated phase?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, variational-principle

In class we learned that Fermat's principle dictates that light travels either along a local minimum or a local maximum of the accumulated optical phase, but the professor only gave examples of local minimum. So in what cases does it ever travel along the local maximum?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167438/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you are on a sphere, and take two points $A$ and $B$.  There is a shortest distance between these points along the great circle connecting $A$ and $B$, and this great circle is a geodesic.  So: instead of firing your laser directly from $A$ towards $B$ along the direct distance, turn around and fire your laser along the geodesic but initially away from $B$ (although this is a bit of a cheat answer).

Comment: I wonder if there is anything one can say in general about the cases in which the action is maximized versus the cases in which is it minimized.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard Feynman’s story about why a French Curve (an elaborately curved manual drafting tool) was interesting?  “No matter how you hold it, the curve is always horizontal at its lowest point”.

[image]

Of course it’s true of all continuous curves:  that’s the joke.

The stationary point, like the lowest point on a curve, is where all the nearby points are about the same. For light rays, that about-the-same length means that the waves will add constructively and collectively strengthen each other. Other places, the distance hence phase is rapidly changing, and so those parts of the wave average to zero.

And now we see why it doesn’t matter whether it’s a maximum or minimum:  like the *top* of the French Curve, which is also always parallel to the floor, all that matters is that it’s a stationary point.